# Unable to correctly download remote image file in PHP with Curl

Tags: php, curl, png, fwrite, fclose

I am trying to download a remote image using Curl, it downloads a file however when I attempt to open the image it on my mac - I get a 'could not be opened' message.

I can see the filename & extension are intact however somehow it hasn't saved as properly as the filesize is 177 bytes, yet i'm expecting the filesize to be around 3kb.

Can anyone suggest why this is? Is the remote site preventing me somehow from downloading the file? I've tried this same code with some other images on other sites and it works fine??

```
    $url = 'http://www.fifaindex.com/static/FIFA16/images/crest/256/light/21.png';
    $saveto = '21.png';

    $ch = curl_init ($url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER,1);
    curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_USERAGENT,'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.8.1.13) Gecko/20080311 Firefox/2.0.0.13');
    $raw = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close ($ch);
    if(file_exists($saveto)){
        unlink($saveto);
    }
    $fp = fopen($saveto,'x');
    fwrite($fp, $raw);
    fclose($fp);
```

Comment: The URL http://www.fifaindex.com/static/FIFA16/images/crest/256/light/21.png is invalid?

Comment: The URL above if clicked appears to load a png for me? Do you not get a logo png of a football/soccer club?

Comment: No, I get a 404 Not Found error. Please check the content of your downloaded file with a text editor to see what you got.

Comment: Weird... i open this file in a text editor and now get the 404 Not found... so I presume somehow the remote site is prevent downloading files?

<html>
<head><title>404 Not Found</title></head>
<body bgcolor="white">
<center><h1>404 Not Found</h1></center>
<hr><center>nginx/1.4.6 (Ubuntu)</center>
</body>
</html>

Comment: I don't think so. Clear the cache of your browser, and try again.

Comment: Hmmm.. if I click a link on the site link below the image loads but when I access the image url directly it doesn't seem to load - the image I am trying to download is on this page here - http://www.fifaindex.com/team/21/fc-bayern/

That is the image I am trying to download remotely - any ideas?

Comment: When I click on the page link the images do not show, I see the 'alt' texts. This site is broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The website you try to get the image from, probably added some restriction so that if the image is called from outside the domain will not be served.

To get around that you can specify the referrer in your CURL options, setting it with the url of the site you want to get the image from.

In your case

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_REFERER, "http://www.fifaindex.com");
```

I tried it myself on my local server and it worked.